# avoid repeating code in swift 4

Tags: swift, generic-function

I would like to create a generic function to avoid repeating while using conditions. Is there any possible ideas to achieve this?
Thanks

```
struct ObjectDataItem {
var name: String
var value: String
}

static func arrayFields(arrayObject: ArrayObject) -> Array<ObjectDataItem> {
    var objectFields = [ObjectDataItem]()

    if let objectCategoryValue = arrayObject.objectCategory {
        let data = [ObjectDataItem(name: ObjectCategoryConstant.objectCategoryKey, value: objectCategory)]
        objectFields.append(contentsOf: data)
    }

    if let objectTypeValue = arrayObject.objectType {
        let data = [ObjectDataItem(name: ObjectTypeConstant.objectTypeKey, value: objectTypeValue)]
        objectFields.append(contentsOf: data)
    }

    if let objectName = arrayObject.objectName {
        let data = [ObjectDataItem(name: ObjectNameConstant.objectNameKey, value: objectName)]
        objectFields.append(contentsOf: data)
    }

    if let countryObjectValue = arrayObject.countryObjectCode {
        let data = [ObjectDataItem(name: countryObjectConstant.countryObjectCodeKey, value: countryObjectValue)]
        objectFields.append(contentsOf: data)
    }

    return objectFields
}
```

Comment: What are the methods `. objectCategoryKey` which are put on `String`?

Comment: Why don't you use a normal `objectFields.append(ObjectDataItem(...))`? Actually you have almost no duplicate code. The code you be probably simplified by changing your data representation. Which is not included in you question.

Comment: hey i have updated now @Sulthan

Comment: Humm i thought maybe i can have generic func somehow to reduce this if contidions repeading.. @Sulthan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use keypaths

```
func arrayFields(arrayObject: ArrayObject) -> Array<ObjectDataItem> {
    var objectFields = [ObjectDataItem]()

    func appendField(key: String, valuePath: KeyPath<ArrayObject, String?>) {
        if let value = arrayObject[keyPath: valuePath] {
            let data = [ObjectDataItem(name: key, value: value)]
            objectFields.append(contentsOf: data)
        }
    }

    appendField(key: ObjectCategoryConstant.objectCategoryKey, valuePath: \ArrayObject.objectCategory)
    appendField(key: ObjectCategoryConstant.objectTypeKey, valuePath: \ArrayObject.objectType)

    return objectFields
}
```

You could go a step further and use a dictionary to lookup the keys, so in the end you would only have to pass in the keypath.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that makes sense to me is to create a dictionary first:

```
var dataDictionary: [String: String] = [:]
dataDictionary[ObjectCategoryConstant.objectCategoryKey] = arrayObject.objectCategory
dataDictionary[ObjectCategoryConstant.objectTypeKey] = arrayObject.objectType
dataDictionary[ObjectCategoryConstant.objectNameKey] = arrayObject.objectName
dataDictionary[countryObjectConstant.countryObjectCodeKey] = arrayObject.countryObjectValue

let objectFields = dataDictionary.map { (name, value) in
    ObjectDataItem(name: name, value: countryObjectValue)
}
```

Dictionary does not contain values that are `nil`. However, you lose the ordering of values (if it's important for you). The simplification is not very big either.

Comment: also in this way again i need to type "ObjectDataItem(name: name, value: arrayObject .countryObjectValue)" this for all .. humm yeah simplification is not big..

Comment: @DicleY Simplify your data model instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use reflection if you do not mind your keys to be the names of your property names  Something like this:

```
func arrayFields(arrayObject: ArrayObject) -> Array<ObjectDataItem> {
    var objectFields = [ObjectDataItem]()
    let objectMirror = Mirror(reflecting: arrayObject)
    for child in objectMirror.children {
        let (propertyName, propertyValue) = child
        objectFields.append(ObjectDataItem(name:propertyName!, value: propertyValue as! String))
    }
    return objectFields
}
```